# Continue inside If statement inside For loop

Tags: java, android

I have a for loop wherein I need to skip some lines.

In a simpler way, here's what I did:

```java
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++){
    if (x == 3) {
        continue;
    }
    Log.i("LOGLOG","LOGLOGLOG");
}
```

Will the continue statement work, as in jump to another iteration of the for loop, or not? If not, what is the best way to do this? Or how can I optimize this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the requirement?

Comment: to skip the log when x is 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes the continue will affect the for loop. You will skip the rest of the code in the current loop block, and start the next iteration.

breaks and continues do not affect if statements, they only affect loops (and breaks for switches).

You can even use [labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) if you need to jump several loops

```
class ContinueWithLabelDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String searchMe = "Look for a substring in me";
        String substring = "sub";
        boolean foundIt = false;

        int max = searchMe.length() - 
                  substring.length();

    test:
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            int n = substring.length();
            int j = i;
            int k = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
                    continue test;
                }
            }
            foundIt = true;
                break test;
        }
        System.out.println(foundIt ? "Found it" : "Didn't find it");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be explicit you can label your loop like this:

```
myLoop : for (int x=0; x<6; x++){
        if (x==3){
            continue myLoop;
        }
        Log.i("LOGLOG","LOGLOGLOG");
    }
```

This will also work for nested loops where you want to continue iterations on the outermost loop.